# MVC 5 OWIN - IsAuthenticated is false on external login (QQ Connect)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I hope someone can help me out with this problem - it's driving me mad! :)

I'm trying to use external login through QQ Connect (OAuth 2.0) using tinysnake's QQ Connect provider: https://github.com/tinysnake/microsoft-owin-security-qq

Everything seems to be going great - I can sign in via my QQ account and I get posted back to my ExternalLoginCallBack-method with the appropriate claims etc. 
I use these values to sign the user in through the IAuthenticationManager - all goes well. However - when I redirect the user to another page and checks if he's logged in - then I get a false value from the IsAuthenticated value... and I can't read any of the claims I set earlier.

It might be a simple fix - but I just can't see it right now :)

Some code:

**AuthConfig:**

```
public static void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    // Normal cookie sign in
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
    });

    // QQ CONNECT
    app.UseQQConnectAuthentication(
        appId: "XXXXXX",
        appSecret: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
}
```

**AccountController:**

```
//
// POST: /Account/ExternalLogin
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
{
    // Request a redirect to the external login provider
    return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
}

//
// GET: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback
[System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    var result = ctx.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie).Result;
    var claims = result.Identity.Claims.ToList();
    var name = claims.First(i => i.Type == "urn:qqconnect:name");

    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod, "QQ"));
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name.Value));

    var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    ctx.Authentication.SignIn(ci);

    // DO OTHER STUFF HERE

    return Redirect("~/");
}
```

All seems to be going well so far...

**HomeController:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new HomeViewModel();

    var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    if (ctx.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)  // <-- THIS RETURNS FALSE
    {
        var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        model.Name = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
        model.IsAuthenticated = true;
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

When I check the ctx.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, I get a false value... and I can't retrieve any of the claims either.

Am I missing something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

## UPDATE

I got my code working by doing this in my AccountController:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    var result = ctx.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie).Result;

    if (result.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // Signed in successfully
        var claims = result.Identity.Claims.ToList();
        var name = claims.First(i => i.Type == "urn:qqconnect:name");

        //claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod, "QQ"));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name.Value));

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
            authenticationManager.SignIn(id);

    }

    return Redirect("~/");
}
```

But the way I see it - here I'm using the ApplicationCookie and NOT the ExternalCookie for signing in... or am I missing something entirely? 
This solution works for me - but I'd like to know if this is the right way to be doing this?

Comment: Having similar issues with this, if anyone can clarify.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, what you are experiencing is expected.  Extremely oversimplifying:

1. The app gets the external information and uses it to create an external cookie
2. the external cookie is sent to your app with the assumption that it is just a temporary cookie that will be used to look up any additional local information about the user and then converted to a local [application] cookie

See [UseCookieAuthentication vs. UseExternalSignInCookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166826/usecookieauthentication-vs-useexternalsignincookie) for a somewhat more thorough breakdown.