# In Azure WebRole always GetExternalLoginInfoAsync is null when Multiple instances

Tags: .net, owin, azure-web-roles

I am using a external authentication (Google y Microsoft) in mvc Project (vb.NET). It is work good when i use only one instance in Azure. But when i use multi instances always fail (return null) but I see than the urls are correct. I use a MachineKey in web.config pero it is not solve nothing. I am using a classic web role.

In development or with a single instance it works. If I put more than one instance it always fails (except if I was authenticated with an instance, in that case the authentication still works)

I only use external cookie, since I only need to determine that they have been authenticated, but not save their identity in a local authentication cookie

```
    Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)

    Dim options = New MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions With {
            .ClientId = "CLIENID",
            .ClientSecret = "SECRET",
            .CallbackPath = New PathString("/signinMS")
        }
    app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            options
            )


    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(New GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions() With {
            .ClientId = "CLIENTID",
            .ClientSecret = "SECRET"
        })

End Sub
```

Example function callback (where is the error)

```
        <AllowAnonymous>
    Public Async Function ExternalLoginCallback() As Task(Of ActionResult)
        Dim loginInfo = Await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()

        If loginInfo Is Nothing Then
            Return Redirect("/")
        End If

        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes().Select(Function(o)
                                                                                                                                        Return o.AuthenticationType
                                                                                                                                    End Function).ToArray())

        Return Redirect("/Areatrabajo")

    End Function
```

[Image Redirects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaUrQ.png)

**PROBLEM FOUND**

Found the problem. Increasing Web Role instances in azure changes the machineKey. For this reason, I cannot use the authentication cookies of the other instances.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166826/usecookieauthentication-vs-useexternalsignincookie

Comment: You need show us more details about the issue.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I have completed the question, including the test code. I only use an external cookie, and that works if I don't use multiple instances. Do I need to use an active cookie?

Comment: You need to try it by yourself !

Comment: I've already tried it, and as I said, it works perfectly in development and with one instance, but if I upload another instance it starts to fail.

Comment: I find offical doc about asp.net  project use ecternal auth services. From the code, I guess maybe there are some different between asp.net and vb.net. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services?view=vs-2019#COMBINE

Comment: Can you give more error details and when it occured ?

Comment: I am trying to help u, and create a demo to test. Util now don't find error, just in login and register page they don't have Loginmodel(RegisterModel) then cause some error. I need  more details then I can help u.

Comment: I don't know how to get more information from that error. This only happens in production and doesn't throw an exception, it just returns null in GetExternalLoginInfoAsync. I have included the image of the call and redirect urls and these are fine. Also it only fails when uploading one more instance in the WebRole. With one does not fail

Comment: I have the same problem. It works on some Azure wepb apps and also locally. But doesn't work with another one. @EugenioFernandez did you solve it by machine key setup?